# Replacing car battery, as soon as the terminals connected locks click on and off

Tags: battery, locks

I just replaced the car battery in a 12 year old Ford Focus, on reconnecting the terminals.
The door locks continuously click on and off.

Any ideas on the cause or suggestions for a fix ?

Comment: Did you operate the keyfob? that may "kick" the computer back under control.

Comment: What diagnosis did you use to determine you needed a new battery?. My guess is you still are not getting sufficient current to your vehicle from your battery. You need to first determine whether or not your battery is fully charged (new or not). Then check and clean battery cables both ends of both sides. I think then your problem will be resolved. (Hopefully).

Comment: sounds like a problem with the vehicle computer.

Comment: Old battery only hold charge for 24 hours after charging, but works OK if I charge from the mains the day before using it. Tried the new one twice, same symptoms, what possible differences are there between batteries ?